# how can I write back to source excel file when I get excel data from data tab?

Tags: excel, file, ms-access, back, microsoft-extensions-logging

So, I want to create one Excel file each for every manager with only one single sheet and place it on OneDrive.

In order to get the data in one place, I am creating another excel file called combined.xlsx.

Now, I can export each workbook to a tab using Data -> Get Data -> From File -> From Workbook .

This is great so far. So, I can read data of 10 excelfiles on 10 sheets in combined.xlsx.

Now, I want to modify contents of one of the tabs and make sure it is reflected to the original file. How can I do this?

Comment: Might be in an answer in this thread if you want to open an account to view code https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1018747-use-vba-to-open-a-document-from-onedrive-and-then-edit-it.html

Comment: it's too unclear what you are trying to do.  Just as you can import into both Excel and Access from each other.  you can export from the Data tab as well.  In both cases you can automate the routine parts of the process with vba.  You can also link tables between the two and the updates will propagate automatically.  Please let us know if exporting from the data tab resolved the problem or use that to clarify your question.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXU-nzVPvMs (first link I found)